# How do I force Process.Start() to complete before proceeding?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, console

I'm creating a console app to process a file and then move it to a 'processed' folder. The main console app calls another app using Process.Start(). This secondary app actually does the work of bulk inserting data into a database. Once the bulk insert is complete, the main app will move the file to another folder and then move on to additional tasks.

In the main app, how do I prevent the code from continuing until the secondary app finishes? I really need to have the first process finish before moving on to the next step.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **WaitForExit()** Methode

Answer (score 7):

Use this method:

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 4):

You might try:

```
Process.Start(...).WaitForExit();
```

Presuming you are using ProcessStartInfo, you might write it more like this:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "SecondProcess.exe";
psi.Arguments = "arg1 arg2";
var process = Process.Start(psi);
if(process != null) process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 3):

See the following links:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305368

http://www.monkeycancode.com/c-run-process-wait-for-it-to-finish

Answer (score 2):

Call [Process.WaitForExit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) before running the next iteration.